# random multi Number list

Tags: python

So I am making hunt the Wumpus as a school project and we have been asked to make a array with random numbers used as the caves but I no clue how to do this the teacher was no help when I asked, I found this website and hope someone could help here is a small bit of code i could not post the whole thing

```
    from random import randint
# The caves array with all the neighbours in it.
caves = []
  if is_alive == True:
    print('You are in cave ' + str(current_cave) + '.')
    print('Exits lead to caves ' + str(caves[current_cave][0]) + ', ' +
        str(caves[current_cave][1]) + ' , ' + str(caves[current_cave][2]) + "," +str(caves[current_cave][3]))
```

Comment: you mean list, not array

Answer (score 0):

This will get you a list of 10 random numbers between 0 and 100

```py
import random
random_list = [random.randint(0, 100) for x in range(10)]
```